Finding the best initial condition of NDSolve for different boundary condition
I have the following Mathematica code, which solves the second-order differential equation:
x1DoublePrime[
  r_] := (Sin[r] x1'[
     r] (-32 (35 + 12 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r]) - 
      3 (15 + 8 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r])^2 x1'[r]^2))/(16 (38 Cos[r] + 
      9 Cos[3 r] + Cos[5 r]))

eqn = x1''[r] == x1DoublePrime[r];

xsol[rc_, k_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{eqn, x1[Pi/2] == k/2, x1[rc] == 0}, 
  x1[r], {r, Pi/2, rc}]

xsol[1, 1]

where $k/2$ is the value at the boundary $r=\pi/2$ and $r_c$ is the initial value of $r$. How do we find suitable $r_c$ for different $k$ values? Is there a suitable algorithm to do that?

For a fixed $k$, are you looking for an interval for $r_c$? Or just any value? (It's not unique, right, even if you restrict $\pi/2 < r_c < \pi$?)

@MichaelE2 actually the value of $r_c$ at which the slope of the curve is zero as shown in Figure 1 of this paper.

I don't see how your comment is related to the question that is stated above. Nor does it answer my question. In the code, you're finding where the value of the function is zero, not where the derivative is zero. I think for a given $k$ there is a continuous range of values of $r_c$ such that $x_1(r_c)=0$, and you could probably express $r_c$ as a function of $p = x_1'(r_c)$, or vice versa. But I don't understand yet what it is that you want.

@MichaelE2 Sorry if I was not able to express my point clearly. The code in the question is just a trivial attempt from my side to reproduce Figure 1 of the paper. I may be wrong regarding the choice of my initial conditions- that is what I wanted to put forward.

anything over rc=Pi gives problems finding solution.
You can try Manipulate and catch error for the values k,rc that do not produce solution.

Code
x1DoublePrime = (Sin[r] x'[
     r] (-32 (35 + 12 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r]) - 
      3 (15 + 8 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r])^2 x'[r]^2))/(16 (38 Cos[r] + 
      9 Cos[3 r] + Cos[5 r]))
eqn = x''[r] == x1DoublePrime;
Manipulate[Module[{sol},
  
  Quiet@Check[
    sol = 
     NDSolveValue[{eqn, x[Pi/2] == k/2, x[rc] == 0}, x, {r, Pi/2, rc}];
    Plot[sol[r], {r, Pi/2, rc}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
     GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red]
    ,
    Row[{"Found Bad values at rc=", rc, ", k=", k}]
    ]
  
  ],
 {{k, 1, "k"}, -5, 5, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{rc, 3/4*Pi, "rc"}, Pi/2 + 1/10*Pi, 5*Pi, 1/10*Pi, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {k, rc}
 ]


can we find the exact value after which Manipulate gives the Found bad
values error?

Numerically, it is at about rc=1.181 Pi. I did not try to find this analytically. You can see this from this code
x1DoublePrime = (Sin[r] x'[
     r] (-32 (35 + 12 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r]) - 
      3 (15 + 8 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r])^2 x'[r]^2))/(16 (38 Cos[r] + 
      9 Cos[3 r] + Cos[5 r]))
eqn = x''[r] == x1DoublePrime;
rc = 1181/1000*Pi;
k = 1;
NDSolveValue[{eqn, x[Pi/2] == k/2, x[rc] == 0}, x, {r, Pi/2, rc}]


Now change rc to this and now singularity shows.
rc = 1182/1000*Pi;
NDSolveValue[{eqn, x[Pi/2] == k/2, x[rc] == 0}, x, {r, Pi/2, rc}]


So for rc=3.710220923889546 is where the NDSolve becomes not happy.

This is really a great way to find rc. Thank you for the informative answer :)

Can we find the exact value after which Manipulate gives the Found bad values error? Or I think, in other words, it should be the value of rc at which the derivative is zero. Should I put this initial condition x'[rc]==0 as well in NDSolve, or is there a different way to find that?

@codebpr it seems for k=1 then at about rc= 1.181 * Pi where singularity happens. This is numerical. I did not attempt to find exact value for rc analytically.  Will update answer with code.

I don't know what the OP wants. And I don't know, and don't have time to figure out, how this Q&A is related to a figure in a paper they referred to in a comment. But there is a better way to integrate the ODE, which has the form $F(r,x',x'')=0$.
The general solution is given by a constant plus sol1, where sol1 (below) is the solution to a first order system that depends on a parameter c, where c may be viewed as a parameter of integration of the reduced-order system obtained from the OP's eqn:
ClearAll[x1DoublePrime, x1, r, k, rc, xp, xpsol, c];
x1DoublePrime[
  r_] := (Sin[r] x1'[
     r] (-32 (35 + 12 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r]) - 
      3 (15 + 8 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r])^2 x1'[r]^2))/(16 (38 Cos[r] + 
      9 Cos[3 r] + Cos[5 r]))

eqn = x1''[r] == x1DoublePrime[r];
bc = {x1[Pi/2] == k/2, x1[rc] == 0};

xpeqn = eqn /. x1 -> Derivative[-1][xp];

xpsol[c_] = (* DSolve solves the OP's eqn, too *)
 DSolve[xpeqn, xp[r], r] /. C[1] -> c // TrigReduce // 
  DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction
(*
{{xp -> Function[{r}, -((4 Sqrt[2])/
     Sqrt[(15 + 8 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r]) (-1 + 
        32 c Sec[r]^6)])]}, {xp -> 
   Function[{r}, (4 Sqrt[2])/
    Sqrt[(15 + 8 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r]) (-1 + 32 c Sec[r]^6)]]}}
*)

eqn1 // ClearAll;
eqn1[] = x1'[r] == Sign[Cos[r]] xp[r];
eqn1[_?Negative] = eqn1[] /. First[xpsol[c]]
eqn1[_?Positive] = eqn1[] /. Last[xpsol[c]]
(*
Derivative[1][x1][r] == -((4 Sqrt[2] Sign[Cos[r]])/
  Sqrt[(15 + 8 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r]) (-1 + 32 c Sec[r]^6)])

Derivative[1][x1][r] == (
 4 Sqrt[2]
   Sign[Cos[r]])/Sqrt[(15 + 8 Cos[2 r] + Cos[4 r]) (-1 + 
    32 c Sec[r]^6)]
*)

This shows a solution sol1 that tracks the corresponding solutions to the OP's BVP and an equivalent IVP for the OP's eqn:
Block[{
    c = 0 + 1/32 + 10^-3, 
    k = 2 * -1.8492374725207468`, 
    p = 6.429092007132865`},
  {sol1 = NDSolveValue[{eqn1[k], x1[0] == 0}, x1, {r, 0, 4 Pi}],
   NDSolveValue[{eqn, x1[Pi/2] == k/2, x1[Pi] == 0}, 
    x1, {r, Pi/2, 2 Pi}],
   NDSolveValue[{eqn, x1[Pi] == 0, x1'[Pi] == p}, 
    x1, {r, Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}]}
  ] // ListLinePlot[#, 
   PlotStyle -> {Automatic, AbsoluteThickness[4], 
     Dashing[{0.05, 0.05}]; Automatic}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> {"\[Integral]x'[r]\[DifferentialD]r", 
     "BVP"[Pi/2, Pi], "IVP"[Pi]}] &


Given two of the three values $k$, $r$, $c$, we can solve for the 3rd:
obj // ClearAll;
obj[r0_?NumericQ, k_?Positive, c1_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{c = c1}, NIntegrate[xp[r] /. Last@xpsol[c], {r, Pi/2, r0}]];
obj[r0_?NumericQ, k_?Negative, c1_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{c = c1}, 
   NIntegrate[xp[r] /. First@xpsol[c], {r, Pi/2, r0}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 32, PrecisionGoal -> 12]];

Block[{r, k, c},
 (* set two of r, k, or c equal to numeric values and
    add the 2nd argument to FindRoot *)
 FindRoot[obj[r, k, c] == k/2, ...]
 ]

Of course it is clear from xpsol that $k$ may be arbitrarily large as $c \rightarrow (1/32)^+$. The growth is slow, and obtaining solutions for large values seems to require extra precision. Also by adjusting the constant of integration added to sol1, the $r$ intercept, which is equivalent to $r_c$ in the OP, may be anything from $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2$.

Thank you for such a detailed and thoughtful answer!
